# install modules from git gives error EISDIR

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I'm working on an open-source project, composes of several repos, and we'd like to make a dedicated repo for code reuse of modules between several projects.

The idea is to set this repo as a dependency in the `package.json`, and to host several modules (all the common ones) in this repo.

Then, once we do `npm install` it should install all modules from this repo in the referencing project.

Even though I added `package.json` int he root of the repo and also inside every one of the modules, I get the following error when doing npm install:

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
```

P.S. We do **NOT** want to publish them to npm because they're not generic and very project-specific.

Comment: What did you put in the package.json file for the consuming project (the one you're doing `npm install` in)? Also, if I remember correctly, NPM install from git will let you install a module from the root of a repo, but not let you reach into the directory structure.

Comment: "replay-common": "git+https://github.com/linnovate/replay-common.git#323a2a53f2e8297aa60a8b60f1559c71b11a5719" (is there a way to omit the commit id?)